# How to pass shipping address when calling PayPal API /payments/payment

Tags: php, api, paypal

I'm using the PayPal API to handle PayPal-payments in my eCommerce-system.

## 1: Get token

v1/oauth2/token

## 2: Create payment

v1/payments/payment

## 3: Execute payment

v1/payments/payment/-ID-/execute/

After step #2 I refer the user to the PayPal-page to login and confirm the payment. The user gets the own shipping address displayed. But I want to override this address with the address the user entered in the checkout of my online-shop.

I tried to set the payer_info -> shipping_address with shipping address object. No errors from paypal but the shipping address is the same.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#shippingaddress-object

Comment: refer below link : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Comment: I dont use the HTML button...

Comment: can you post an example of the full array you are sending?

Comment: You're going to have to give us a sample call (not code, the actual data you're sending to PayPal) to help us diagnose this

Answer (score 2):

This is a US Merchant solution only. Take a look at this [Paypal Developer Documentation here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_BillingShippingAddress/).

When is comes to Paypal you almost always can override settings you just need to dig into the documentation and find the right combination. What I think you need is found in the second choice down:

> Use the address_override variable. / 
>   See Overriding Addresses Stored With PayPal.

I'm in class at the moment so I can help more later if you need but for us to really help you out we need to see code samples of what your already attempting.

**EDIT**
So do what your already doing sounds right, just add the override commands where appropriate.

Please add your code if your still having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a 'shipping_address'
   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#shippingaddress-object
2. Add the 'shipping_address' to your 'item_list'
   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#itemlist-object